# Premiere Pro: how to set pixel-perfect rectangle mask's size and position?

Tags: adobe-premiere, mask

I'm currently using Adobe Premiere Pro version 14.8.0.

Can not find the way to create a mask other than [draw it by hand](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/how-to/create-clip-masks.html), but this method doesn't allow to create a mask of exactly specified size and put it into exact position.

Is there any proven way to achieve my aim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the solution: [Track Matte Key](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/how-to/add-track-matte-key.html) effect will do the job.